# Error in query string: Error processing job in Ubuntu terminal for bq load

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, google-bigquery

I have a bash script that runs screaming frog SEO spider crawls on a list of domains and sends the internal tables to BigQuery. Usually this works quite well on an automated basis but now the internal tables are not loading into bigquery and I am getting this error when I look at the VM logs:

```
Error in query string: Error processing job 'project-name:bqjob_': Duplicate column 'Response_Header__Content_Length' for table
'internal_20240212_{}_source'.
```

The VM uses an Ubuntu pro operating system.I've updated to the latest version of screaming frog in the SSH as well. I think perhaps I should add some commands to my bash script so that it can deal with 'duplicate columns' when loading into BigQuery - but since I'm not great with bash scripting I would like some help on this. Here is a snippet of the bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

domain=$(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/client-domain)

configpath="/home/user/Config.seospiderconfig"

# initiate crawl from screamingfrogseospider without GUI (headless) and define the output folder as the crawl-data directory
screamingfrogseospider --crawl "$domain" --headless --config "$configpath" --output-folder ~/crawl-data/ \
--export-tabs "Internal:All,Directives:All,Hreflang:All,Pagination:All,Structured Data:All,Sitemaps:All" --overwrite --bulk-export "All Inlinks"


now=$(date +"%Y%m%d") #defines date
filename=$(echo "$domain" | cut -d'.' -f1)

if ! bq ls ${filename} &>/dev/null; then
  bq mk ${filename} # creates dataset in bigquery based on the filename
fi

# Check if the file exists
if [ ! -f ~/crawl-data/internal_all.csv ]; then
    echo "Error: internal_all.csv does not exist."
    exit 1
fi
# replace null values with spaces in the csv files
tr '\0' ' ' < ~/crawl-data/internal_all.csv > ~/crawl-data/internal_all_clean.csv
bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV --allow_quoted_newlines --allow_jagged_rows --ignore_unknown_values \
${filename}.internal_${now} ~/crawl-data/internal_all_clean.csv
```